# Obtener un Double de un archivo

Tags: c#, regex

Estoy leyendo un archivo usando regex, pero cuando llego a un numero con decimales y lo convierto

```
public FarmacoEntity ObtenerFarmaco(int linea)
    {
        FarmacoEntity farmaco = new FarmacoEntity();
        string line = File.ReadLines(path).Skip(linea).Take(1).First();
        Regex CSVParser = new Regex(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*(?![^\"]*\"))");
        //Separating columns to array
        string[] valores = CSVParser.Split(line);
        farmaco.Nombre = valores[1];
        farmaco.Descripcion = valores[2];
        farmaco.CasaProductora = valores[3];
        farmaco.Precio = Convert.ToDouble(Regex.Match(valores[4], @"\d+").Value, NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo);
        farmaco.Existencia = int.Parse(Regex.Match(valores[5], @"\d+").Value, NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo);

        return farmaco;

    }
```

al tener el precio en la posicion 4 me lo manda redondeado hacia arriba por ejemplo tengo 408.07 me manda 409 como lo mando con decimales

Comment: Usa decimal para precios en lugar de double

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en que estás filtrando todo lo que no sean números en el Regex, y '.' (o ',', según la configuración) no es un número.

Si haces

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match("123.54", @"\d+").Value);
```

el resultado es *123*. A partir de aquí, ya no tienes decimales (porqué te sale 409 en vez de 408 no queda explicado, yo apostaría por un error de programación en otro sitio).

No sé muy bien cual es tu formato, si hay alguna razón por la que necesites hacer el regex deberías añadir el separador de decimales; para hacerlo estándar:

```
String regex = @"\d+\";
regex += Regex.Escape(NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.CurrencyDecimalSeparator);
regex += @"\d+";
Console.WriteLine("Regex " + regex);
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match("123.54", regex).Value);
```

[Aquí tienes un ejemplo.](https://ideone.com/ACih8k)

Y por último el comentario de gbianchi es correcto, usar formatos de tipo flotante (como *Double*) para cantidades de dinero (entre otras cosas) puede ser complicado porque hay límites en la representación de los valores que puede causar problemas; hay unas cuantas preguntas con buenas respuestas al respecto.

Comment: Esto funciono, gracias! Pero quisiera saber como funcina esa respuesta por que no la logro comprender al 100

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no entiendes? La cuestión principal es que *\d* reconoce dígitos del 0 al 9, pero no el punto o la coma.

Comment: Eso, soy relativamente nuevo en c# y acabo de empezar a utilizar regex